# python.exe: No module named pyuic5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to convert my .ui file to py but pyuic5 is not recognized

[image]

And when i go to my python directory this error message appears

[image]

how to fix this error?

Comment: try: `python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic filename.ui -o filename.py -x`

Comment: It worked! thanks! May I have an explanation on why i get that error?

Comment: According to the error message it seems that the cause is the permissions, maybe if you open the cmd in admin mode it will be fixed although I do not recommend it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more generic option is:

```
python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic filename.ui -o filename.py -x
```